# The server is not terminated

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using threads to have a server listening for both TCP and UDP messages. Here is the code:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import socket 

Listening_Port = 5005
Listening_IP = "127.0.0.1"

#define UDP listening function
def UDPListen():

    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # IPv4, UDP
    sock.bind((Listening_IP, Listening_Port))
    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "UDP Messsage from address: ", address
        print "Message: ", data

#define a TCP listening function
def TCPListen():
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # IPv4, TCP
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((Listening_IP, Listening_Port))
    while True:
        sock.listen(1)
        conn, address = sock.accept()
        print "TCP connection from", address
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "Mesage: ", data
        conn.close()

# main function
def main():

    ThreadUDP = Thread(target=UDPListen)
    ThreadTCP = Thread(target=TCPListen)

    print "Starting Server..."
    ThreadUDP.start()
    ThreadTCP.start()
    print "Server Started!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that when I press `ctrl + c` (even multiple times), the program is not terminated and I should close the console.

I tried something like this for `def main()`, but it didn't work:

```
def main():

    ThreadUDP = Thread(target=UDPListen)
    ThreadTCP = Thread(target=TCPListen)
    try:
        print "Starting Server..."
        ThreadUDP.start()
        ThreadTCP.start()
        print "Server Started!"
    # Hit Break / Ctrl-C to exit
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')
        raise
```

---

Updated code according to the solution offered in the answers:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import socket 

Listening_Port = 5005
Listening_IP = "10.0.0.3"

#define UDP listening function
def UDPListen():

    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # IPv4, UDP
    sock.bind((Listening_IP, Listening_Port))
    while not eve.isSet():
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "UDP Messsage from address: ", address
        print "Message: ", data

#define a TCP listening function
def TCPListen():
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # IPv4, TCP
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((Listening_IP, Listening_Port))
    while not eve.isSet():
        sock.listen(1)
        conn, address = sock.accept()
        print "TCP connection from", address
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "Mesage: ", data
        conn.close()

# main function
def main():

    ThreadUDP = Thread(target=UDPListen)
    ThreadTCP = Thread(target=TCPListen)
    eve = threading.Event()
    print "Starting Server..."
    ThreadUDP.start()
    ThreadTCP.start()
    print "Server Started!"

    try:
        while True:
            eve.wait(2)
    except Exception:
        eve.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but I received an error:

```
NameError: Global name 'threading' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are sending packets to the Python server?

Comment: @MaximeB I solved the first problem, the program is now receiving the messages, but as I mentioned it is not terminated when I press `"ctrl +c"` (even multiple times)

Comment: Can you try : ThreadUDP.daemon = True and same for ThreadTCP?

Comment: @MaximeB I added these two lines, but as soon as the program starts, it prints ` "Starting Server..."  "Server Started!"` and then exits the program.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is that you run your `listeners` in a thread - meaning that signals caught in the `main` should somehow signal the threads.

use `threading.Event` and then in the main function :

```
eve = threading.Event()
<start your threads>
try:
    while True:
        eve.wait(2)
except Exception
    eve.set()
```

and in the threads instead of `while True` use `while not eve.isSet():`

Comment: I added what you have mentioned and added the new code to my post, but I received an error: `NameError: Global name 'threading' is not defined`

Comment: By the way, when I use `while not eve.isSet()` instead of `while true` in the threads, I receive a nameError that `global name eve is not defined`. I solved this by defining `eve` as global, but the program is still not terminated after pressing `ctrl + c` for several times.